# Use NativeScript preview locally behind proxy

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm attempting to do some local NativeScript development, and preview the app on my phone.  I've used this line to create a new sample app:

```
tns create HelloWorld --template tns-template-blank-ng
```

I also installed the NativeScript preview and playground apps on my phone.  I was able to preview the app by running the `tns preview` command locally, and scanning the code on my playground app, just as documented.  However, my regular connection is behind a proxy, and when I attempt to preview while connected to that network, the app never loads on my phone, but just displays a blank screen.  I've used the `tns proxy set` command to set the proxy for the NativeScript cli, configured the proxy connection properly on both my laptop and phone (I can connect to other resources just fine).  I've also tried with and without my laptop's IP address added to the "ignore proxy" list on my phone's WiFi connection.  My phone is an Android, and my laptop is running Fedora 30, if that matters.

To summarize, **is there any way to use the NativeScript playground app behind a proxy?**

Comment: Your phone and machine should be on same network, if you are running th proxy within your machine (not network) then you will have to configure same proxy network on your phone too.

Comment: @Manoj, thanks for responding.  The proxy is running at a network level, and I have configured the proxy on the connection on my phone and on my laptop.

Comment: @Manoj I am also facing the same problem can you please elaborate on the problem and how to tackle, my PC is running on the same wifi as my phone and both have proxies configured but tns preview is not working when connected to proxy network

Comment: @SimpleGeek can you explain how you solved this issue??

Comment: @Pritishkumar, I haven't been able to solve this issue yet.  My earlier comment to Manoj was explaining how my network is currently configured.

Comment: @SimpleGeek Is there any workaround this?

Comment: @Pritishkumar Unfortunately, I have not found a workaround.  If you find something, please let me know!

Comment: @SimpleGeek sure